# What's wrong with my code for pangram function?

Tags: python, function, pangram

I wrote this code for a function to check for pangram and it doesn't work. I need an explanation as to where I am getting it wrong.

```
def is_mypangram(phrase):
    alphabets = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    for letters in alphabets:
        for char in phrase:
            if letters not in phrase:
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

Comment: For starters, you can wait until you finish iterating before returning. Also, please stop shouting, it's very rude.

Comment: Give a [mcve], *"somehow it's not accurate"* isn't a good problem description. Also show some debugging effort - you might find http://pythontutor.com/ useful if you can't visualise what's going on.

Comment: ok, thank you. let me rephrase that.

Comment: How is *"it doesn't work"* any better? Read the article. Errors (give traceback)? Unexpected outputs (what did you expect, and what did you get instead)?

Comment: unexpected outputs. it didn't indicate any error. just that if i put in phrases that aren't pangram it still returns them as True.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break your code line by line.

`for letters in alphabets` takes *one letter at a time*, so we start with *a*

`for char in phrase` takes the first char in phrase, let's use `example` as the 
phrase string. So `char` is *e*

`if letters not in phrase` wait, this check if `a` is in `phrase`. If so, it returns `False`.

Otherwise it returns `True`.

You basically don't use your `char` anywhere. You also don't continue to loop; this will **only check the first letter in the alphabet and the first letter of phrase.**